# How to Use Dynamic Sql on Update Command?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Had Update Command. Just Like this.

```
Update DispatchExceptions
SET TYPE='MWM'
WHERE ID=9801246
```

I want to fire same command using dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(20)=N'TYPE'
DECLARE @ColumnValue char(3)='MWM'
DECLARE @ID INTEGER = 9801246
declare @Query nvarchar(max)


SET @Query = 'Update DispatchExceptions SET '+ QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + '''=' + @ColumnValue + '''WHERE ID =' + @ID +''

EXEC (@Query)
```

But it show following error.

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Update DispatchExceptions SET [TYPE]'=MWM'WHERE ID =' to data type int.
```

How can I use dynamic sql in the situation. Any suggestion.

Comment: Looks like you've got your quote on the wrong side of the equals i.e. it should be `[TYPE]='MWM'` not `[TYPE]'=MWM'`. And something similar for your ID.

Comment: Well done on the use of `QUOTENAME` on `@ColumnName` , but `@ColumnValue` and `@ID` should be parametrised, not concatenated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is specifically the part `' + @ID`. `@ID` is the datatype `int`, which has a higher datatype precedence than `nvarchar`; thus any other expressions will be implicitly cast to an `int` (and as I'm sure you're aware, `'Update DispatchExceptions SET...'` isn't an `int`).

If you parametrise your query, you won't have this problem:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname = N'TYPE'; --Changed the datatype here to sysname, as the caters for all possible object names
                                       --sysname is actually a synonym for nvarchar(128), and 128 is the maximum length for an object's name
DECLARE @ColumnValue char(3) = 'MWM';
DECLARE @ID integer = 9801246;
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX);   

SET @Query = N'Update DispatchExceptions SET ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N' = @value WHERE ID = @ID;';

EXEC sp_executesql @Query,
                   N'@Value char(3), @ID int',
                   @Value = @ColumnValue,
                   @ID = @ID;
```

Also, to the OP, well done on the use of `QUOTENAME`. This is far too often missed out, and thus leaves your (dynamic) SQL open to injection.

Comment: That's a much better solution.

Comment: Thank's its helps Lot.

Comment: You're welcome @MumbaiKandivali. If it solves the problem, please mark it as a solution so that others with the same problem will know that this helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The DBMS fails to add

```
9801246
```

to

```
Update DispatchExceptions SET [TYPE]'=MWM'WHERE ID =
```

because the latter is a string and canot be converted to number, which would be necessary in order to add the number 9801246 to it :-)

One solution:

```
DECLARE @ID varchar(7) = '9801246'
```

Another solution:

```
SET @Query = 'Update DispatchExceptions SET '+ QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) +
             '''=' + @ColumnValue + '''WHERE ID =' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(7)) +''
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply cast your @ID as varchar and correct quotation before @ColumnValue as given below:

```
SET @Query = 'Update DispatchExceptions SET '+QUOTENAME(@ColumnName)+'='''+@ColumnValue+''' WHERE ID ='+cast(@ID as varchar)+'';
```